# How to achieve rollback in transactions in mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, transactions, mongoose

I am using mongoose over mongodb.

In a request and response from nodejs express server, generally requires a no of queries to mongodb through mongoose.

In many cases it may happen, if first a few queries executes successfully and rest all failed under a transaction.

Now i need to rollback my db state to the very initial state of db.

So how can i rollback efficiently in mongodb?
Please provide some suitable references.

Comment: If you want to fit in with MongoDB functionality, a "compensating" transaction is often a useful option. In this case, it would "undo" whatever changes were made.

Comment: queries don't change documents. what exactly do you want to rollback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Hector. If you need multiple document transactions then Mongo might not be a good fit for you. Can you embed your data structure in a single document? Then you can get the rollback you are looking for.

Another option is to look at the Mongo clone TokuMX which provides transactions across multiple documents.

Comment: TokuMX transactions are not compatible with sharding.

Comment: Since MongoDB 4.0.0 (and Mongoose 5.2.0) there is now support for Transactions in MongoDB.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

Answer (score 4):

Going through mongo tutorials

Here is a link i found for making two phase commits ( may be it is not guaranteed ) :

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for traditional ACID database transactions in MongoDB regardless of what you put on top of it. This is not an issue with Mongoose or Express.js, it's a characteristic of MongoDB.

MongoDB supports atomic operations which means that saving to a collection is guaranteed to succeed completely or fail, in other words you won't get partial updates to a single document in a collection. But there is no support for multi-updates in a single transaction.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-support-transactions

Comment: Is there any way to manage these multiple query transactions rollback??

Comment: If you *really* need this, I would suggest you reconsider if MongoDB is the right choice for your project. Perhaps you should use a traditional relational database that supports this out of the box.