# Mongoose (mongodb) batch insert, delete, update and no operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Hi all**, I am using mongodb version ‘`mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.0.7-signed`’ and middle man mongoose version ‘`4.2.5`’ trying to batch insertion, deletion and updating.  I've searched for a few days but did not find anything that the answer was an unequivocal.

I have an array list which is below, the array list has four object which has different tag level.

```
var mangoobjectList = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Gopal Vog', origin: 'Rajshahi', tag: 0 },//no change
    { id: 2, name: 'Himsagor', origin: 'Dhaka', tag: 1 },//insert
    { id: 3, name: 'Langra', origin: 'Sylet', tag: 2 },//update
    { id: 4, name: 'Amrupali', origin: 'Chuadanga', tag: 3 }//delete
];
```

> I mean to say that the  tag = 0 --no operation, tag = 1 -- inset tag =
>   2 – update, tag = 3 -- delete

Now I want **save** this array by **one shot into mongodb database**. If anyone object is failed then whole array will roll back. Any idea or solution will be appreciate.

Comment: Have you looked at this link https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-support-transactions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487233/how-to-achieve-rollback-in-transactions-in-mongo

Comment: @DaveCoast, ok, but has their any alternative way?

Comment: @DaveCoast, I want to change my database, can you tell me which nosql database will be perfect for me.

Comment: most nosql databases does not support transactions. If it is important to you, you should use SQL.

Comment: I added some example code below .You could use the plugin to perform a transaction in your situation. If you don't care much about performance, maybe it could work for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a 'transaction' but mongodb does not support it. Documents in mongodb are updated atomically - you cannot rollback from batch inserts/updates/removes. Preferably you should rethink your database design.

You could also implement a "transaction-like" method, described in mongodb documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Also, you could use a mongoose plugin for that - probably the easiest option:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-transaction

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Transaction = require('mongoose-transaction')(mongoose);

var mangoobjectList = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Gopal Vog', origin: 'Rajshahi', tag: 0 },//no change
    { id: 2, name: 'Himsagor', origin: 'Dhaka', tag: 1 },//insert
    { id: 3, name: 'Langra', origin: 'Sylet', tag: 2 },//update
    { id: 4, name: 'Amrupali', origin: 'Chuadanga', tag: 3 }//delete
];

var transaction = new Transaction();

mangoobjectList.forEach(function(doc){
  switch(doc.tag) {
    case 1:
        transaction.insert('collectionName', doc);
        break;
    case 2:
        transaction.update('collectionName', doc._id, doc);
        break;
    case 3:
        transaction.remove('collectionName', doc._id);
        break;    
    default:
        //do nothing
}
});
  
transaction.run(function(err, docs){
  // your code here 
});
```